# Do there exist, $\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{3 \left| x\right| +2 x}{7 \left| x\right| -5 x}$?

Tags: limits, absolute-value

Here is why I think the limit does not exists.

[link to image if mathjax doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVarx.jpg)

$\lim \limits_{x \to ∞ } \frac{3|x|+2x}{7|x|-5x}$ == $\lim \limits_{1/h \to 0 } \frac{3|1/h|+2(1/h)}{7|1/h|-5(1/h)}$

$\lim \limits_{1/h \to 0^+ } \frac{3|1/h|+2(1/h)}{7|1/h|-5(1/h)}$ == $\lim \limits_{1/h \to 0^+ } \frac{3+2}{7-5}$ == $\frac{5}{2}$

$\lim \limits_{1/h \to 0^- } \frac{3|1/h|+2(1/h)}{7|1/h|-5(1/h)}$ == $\lim \limits_{1/h \to 0^- } \frac{-3+2}{-7-5}$ == $\frac{1}{12}$

left limit does not match the right limit. so i think the limit does not exist. Is this solution correct?

Edit: please note here the question is whether the limit to the given equation exists or not, if it does what is it.

Comment: As $x\to\infty$ you have that $x$ is always positive at some point on...  So $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{3|x|+2x}{7|x|-5x}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{3x+2x}{7x-5x}$........  Can you continue?

Comment: You did not need any of this changing to $\frac{1}{h}\to 0$ nonsense.  Note the difference between $x\to\infty$ and $x\to -\infty$ and how it relates to $\frac{1}{h}\to 0^+$ versus $\frac{1}{h}\to 0^-$... Your finding the limits didn't match is just showing that the limit as $x\to\infty$ doesn't match the limit as $x\to -\infty$... but we didn't care about $x\to -\infty$ in the first place

Comment: is changing to  1/h→0 completely invalid?

Comment: Completely invalid? No, but you needed to look *only* as it approached 0 from the right.  Unnecessary?  Yes.

Comment: Sir D--- It's invalid in the sense that making $1/h \to 0$ allows $1/h$ to go through positive *or* negative values, but the original limit (after making $x=1/h$) only has $1/h \to 0^+$.

Comment: Since $x>0, h=\frac 1x>0.$ You only need to take the limit in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

When I started studying calculus, there still were books that distinguished between $+\infty$, $-\infty$ and $\infty$ (unsigned infinity).

The definition of $\smash{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}}\,f(x)=l$ at unsigned infinity was

> for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M>0$ such that, for all $|x|>M$, it holds that $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

I don't think this has *ever* been useful, and nowadays it's quite rare to find it. Usually $\infty$ means what in those times was denoted as $+\infty$. Why is it useless? Because that (useless) limit exists if and only if the limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ exist and they're equal. Which happens for rational functions when the degree of the numerator doesn't exceed the degree of the denominator: not so a general context.

In your case, you have
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 5/2 & x>0 \\[6px] 1/12 & x<0 \end{cases}
$$
so there's no doubt what the limit at positive and negative infinity are. Unless your textbook or instructor uses the old-fashioned unsigned infinity.

---

The “unsigned infinity” has its uses, though: when doing with analytic functions, it is common to “compactify” the complex plane by adding a single point, namely $\infty$. And the notion of limit at $\infty$ is exactly the same as the one spelled above, but with the variable in the complex numbers.

Comment: i was only told that there is only one limit to (3|x|+2x)/(7|x|-5x) which was 5/2. thinking that it was valid to convert to divide by zero format i arrived at two limits.

Comment: if i understand it correct, you are also saying the limit is 5/2 only?

Comment: @SirDevil Yes, the most common conventions identify $\infty$ and $+\infty$.

Comment: dumb question, provided the unsigned infinity, does the limit exists?

Comment: @SirDevil In that case no, because the limit at $+\infty$ differs from the limit at $-\infty$.

Comment: Note $\infty$ (as opposed to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$) is still used all the time in complex analysis.  The definition is the same as the one quoted, except $x$ and $l$ are allowed to be complex.

Comment: @GEdgar That's a quite different setting, though.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, right.

Answer (score 0):

$$\underset{x\to +\infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{3 \left| x\right| +2 x}{7 \left| x\right| -5 x}=\underset{x\to +\infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{3 x +2 x}{7x -5 x}=\underset{x\to +\infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{5x}{2x}=\frac{5}{2}$$
$$\underset{x\to -\infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{3 \left| x\right| +2 x}{7 \left| x\right| -5 x}=\underset{x\to -\infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{-3 x +2 x}{-7x -5 x}=\underset{x\to -\infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{-x}{-12x}=\frac{1}{12}$$
The limits at $\infty$ are two and they both exist. The limit at $x=0$ does not exist.

---

[image]